# convert Object list to string

Tags: c#

Can someone explain me how to convert a "System.Collections.Generic" to `List<string>`?
From `List<Tag> lsTag = new List<Tag>();` to `List<string> list = new List<string>();`

And Tag is a class. Thanks in advance.

What I tried is:

`.ToList<string>` and `stringbuilder`

I read a .xml file and I try to add items from my `List<Tag> lsTag = new List<Tag>();` to a Silverlight ListBox control. But the only result I see is Clipboard.Tag (the name of my class). Hopefully now is clearer..

## update

That's my class for the .xml file:

```
namespace Clipboard {
public class Tag {
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<CodeFragments> lsTags = new List<CodeFragments>();
}
```

That's to other class for the .xml file:

```
 public class CodeFragments {
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string tagURL { get; set; }
    public string titel { get; set; }
    public string body { get; set; }
}
```

That's my .xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeFragments>
  <Tag name="codeFrag1">
<oFragments tagURL="fragm1-1" titel="signatuur1-1" body="public static void main(String args[])" />
<oFragments tagURL="fragm1-2" titel="signatuur1-2" body="public static void main(String args[])" />
```

```
<Tag name="codeFrag2">
<oFragments tagURL="fragm2-1" titel="signatuur2-1" body="public static void main(String args[])" />
<oFragments tagURL="fragm2-2" titel="signatuur2-2" body="public static void main(String args[])" />
```

```
</CodeFragments>
```

That my class to read the .xml file:

```
public void LoadXMLFile() {
        WebClient xmlClient = new WebClient();
        xmlClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(XMLFileLoaded);
        xmlClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("codeFragments.xml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    }
    public void XMLFileLoaded(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e) {
        if (e.Error == null) {
            string xmlData = e.Result;
            XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlData);
            var tagsXml = from c in xDoc.Descendants("Tag") select c.Attribute("name");
            List<Tag> lsTags = new List<Tag>();
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            foreach (string tagName in tagsXml) {
                Tag oTag = new Tag();
                oTag.name = tagName;
                var tags = from d in xDoc.Descendants("Tag")
                           where d.Attribute("name").Value == tagName
                           select d.Elements("oFragments");
                var tagXml = tags.ToArray()[0];

                foreach (var tag in tagXml) {
                    CodeFragments oFragments = new CodeFragments();
                    oFragments.tagURL = tag.Attribute("tagURL").Value;
                    oFragments.body = tag.Attribute("body").Value;
                    oFragments.titel = tag.Attribute("titel").Value;
                    oTag.lsTags.Add(oFragments);
                }                    
                lsTags.Add(oTag);
            }
            //list = lsTags.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList();
            lsBox.ItemsSource = lsTags;            
        }
    }
```

---

Problem solved! With none of these given answers... Thanks for your reply anyway!

Answer (score 5):

Your question is very low on quality, but I guess what you want is this:

```
List<string> list = lsTag.Select(x => x.Name.ToString()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Silverlight developer, but my guess is that you need to override `ToString` in your `Tag` class.  The Silverlight control is probably calling `ToString` on each Tag item.  By default, `ToString` outputs the name of the class for most complex types.  So you just need to do something like:

```
public class Tag {

  //just guessing on your implementation that you have
  //a private variable that you want displayed in the list
  private String _tagName;

  //your implementation here

  public override String ToString(){
    //what you want the Tag to display
    return _tagName;
  }

  //more implementation
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I try this too. I'll give you all more information. just a second.